# Please look at the below code I wrote to make an appointment schedule in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am working on an appointment schedule on Google Sheets. My sheet is connected to a Google form so I can get form responses in my project. My vision for this project is that people select a time slot from the form and that time slot changes to "Booked" in the weekly schedule instead of Dr A or Dr B etc. Please see the lower part of the image for reference. I am doing this through coding in Google Apps Script. But the code is not working. It says execution completed but nothing happens on my sheet. Please look at the code below and help me. Thanks!

```
function booking() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var cusRec = ss.getSheetByName("Customer Record");
  var appSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Appointment sheet for psychologists");
  
  var cusDate = cusRec.getRange(2,7).getValue();
  var cusTime = cusRec.getRange(2,8).getValue();
  var cusPsy = cusRec.getRange(2,9).getValue();

  var appDate = appSheet.getRange(3,2).getValue();
  var appTime = appSheet.getRange(5,1).getValue();
  var appPsy = appSheet.getRange(5,2).getValue();  

  if (cusDate == appDate && cusTime == appTime && cusPsy == appPsy)
  {
    appSheet.getRange("B5").setValue("Booked");
  }
}
```

[This is a picture of the two sheets I am working with][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCRid.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you run some loggers to check with part of your data is not matching. Most like it's an issue with formatting or empty spaces, etc.

Try adding this

```
console.log(cusDate, appDate, cusDate == appDate)
console.log(cusTime, appTime, cusTime == appTime)
console.log(cusPsy, appPsy, cusPsy == appPsy)
```

And see what the output is.